# How can I use SpEL to evaluate a subobject property where the subobject might be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I want to evaluate

```
"user.name"
```

but `user` might be null, which of course results in an NPE is there a way to say only try to get name if user is not null? otherwise return null.

I read about the Elvis syntax, but I'm not sure how to apply it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [safe navigation operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation) like this:

```
user?.name
```

This has the exact same behavior you describe - if the user is `null`, the expression will be evaluated to `null`, otherwise it will be evaluated to the value of `user.name`.